# Shopify reorder sections and editable content?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to define the schema so my sections can be edited and reordered in the admin. I have this at the bottom of two of my section.liquid files.

```
{% schema %}
{
  "presets": [
    {
      "category": "Custom Content",
      "name": "Text",
      "settings": {
        "heading": "Hello World"
      }
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

When I keep the "heading": "Hello World" I get the error

`Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
 Errors: Invalid preset "Text": cannot add settings because there are no 
 settings defined in the schema.`

I'm not entirely sure where else I need to define the settings?

Also when I get rid of the settings section "heading": "Hello World" it saves but the sections can't be reordered, I thought that was enabled when the "presets" part is in the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of code is missing.
Before defining preset values for settings you'll need to define settings themselves as explained in documentation here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/sections#settings

HTH